# Cypress error in version 13.6.4 | cy.task() must only be invoked from the spec file or support file

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, xlsx

I am using below version for cypress automation

```
Cypress package version: 13.6.4
Cypress binary version: 13.6.4
Electron version: 25.8.4
Bundled Node version:
18.15.0
```

I am reading data from Xlsx file and converting to json then facing issue when running in --headed mode.

Case 1 : When running my code with command "npx cypress run --headed" then getting error in browser

[cy.task() must only be invoked from the spec file or support file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdaG7.png)

Case 2 : when running my code with command "npx cypress run" then not getting this error
[Data Read from Xlsx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfExj.png)

Sharing my code used in cypress

1. Added a folder in cypress with name as "read-xlsx.js" and added code

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx')
const fs = require('fs')

const readData = (testCaseIdData) => {
    try{
        const testDataFilePath = "cypress\\fixtures\\TestData.xlsx"
        // const workbook = XLSX.readFile(testDataFilePath);
        const buf = fs.readFileSync(testDataFilePath);
        const workbook = XLSX.read(buf, {type: 'buffer'})
        const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0]; // Assuming data is in the first sheet
        const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
        const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
        // Filter JSON data based on test case ID column
        const filteredData = jsonData.filter((row) => row['TestCaseId'] === testCaseIdData);
        console.log(filteredData[0])
        return filteredData[0]
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
    readData,
}
```

2. Added another file in plugins folder with name as "index.js" and added code

```
const readXlsxData = require('./read-xlsx')

module.exports = (on, config) =>{
    on('task',{
        'readXlsxData': readXlsxData.readData
    })
}
```

3. update cypress.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity:false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)
    },
    specPattern:'cypress/e2e/practice_code.js'
  },
});
```

4. Finally In my test spec.js file

```
describe('Reading XLSX file and converting to JSON', () => {
  it('should convert XLSX data to JSON based on test case ID column', () => {
    const testCaseIdData = 'TC_002'; // Update this with the test case ID you want to filter
    var data = cy.task('readXlsxData', testCaseIdData)
    cy.log(data)
    console.log(data)
  });
});
```

Please help to resolve !!

I am expecting my result should be printed when test is running.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Cypress Documentation - Best Practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices), it is an anti-pattern to use the returned value of a command, including `cy.task()`.

> **Anti-Pattern:**  Trying to assign the return value of Commands with const, let, or var.
>
> **Best Practice:** Use aliases and closures to access and store what Commands yield you.

So your test code should be like this:

```js
cy.task('readXlsxData', testCaseIdData)
  .then(data => {
    cy.log(data)
    console.log(data)
  })
```

Comment: I already tried the same but still same result.

Comment: No, it cannot possibly be the same result - using correct syntax gives you different things in the log.